# There is a problem in width property for DropDownList 

Tags: asp.net

I have dropdownlist and textbox and both of them have width property set to 100px,
why the dropdownlist is smaller than textbox.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="100" ></asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="100" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `<select width="100px">` or `<select style="width:100px"`? If it's the former, change it to the latter.